# Schedule execution of a control indicator script

Tags: servicenow

I have a control indicator that has a script to execute. The control and its indicator have the frequency defined.

I want to schedule execution of this script.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that the process that is supposed to execute these scripts was inactive.

Going to System Scheduler > Scheduled Jobs and then searching for '*GRC' I 
found the job 'GRC indicator nightly run'.

In the Related Links, click 'Configure Job Definition'. 
From there, check the Active box and you can verify by using Execute Now.

I hope this helps someone besides me.